# Python Parallel Sorting

Tags: python, sorting

I have `list1`:

```
['GM2', 'GM1', 'GM3']
```

and `list2`:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

How do you sort this in a way where it shows. Basically would like the element at index 0 in `list1` to correspond to the element in index 0 in `list2`.

```
GM1 B
GM2 A
GM3 C
```

Comment: `zip(a, b)` should workd, assuming, `a` and `b` stores the arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The builtin [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function will match the corresponding elements so that you get a result of tuples, where each element is made up from an element in `list1` and its corresponding element in `list2`:

```
>>> list1 = ['GM2', 'GM1' ,'GM3']
>>> list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> result = sorted(zip(list1, list2))
>>> result
[('GM1', 'B'), ('GM2', 'A'), ('GM3', 'C')]
```

Comment: And then add a `sorted(result)`?

Comment: @KevinGuan no, the sorting should be done first, to each list individually. See my edited answer.

Comment: Nah, then your answer become incorrect. Check OP's expected output: `GM1 B` and `GM2 A`.

Comment: @KevinGuan good catch. Wasn't paying as much attention as I should have. Just applying `sorted` as you suggested is indeed the way to go.